# RadioButtons not grouping properly in an ASP.NET 2.0 repeater

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, asp.net-2.0, repeater

I've got a web app in ASP.NET 2.0 in which I need to have a highly customized grid.  One of the columns in the grid contains a radio button for each row.

I'm implementing it as a `Repeater` control, with a `div` in each `ItemTemplate`.  The problem is that the radio buttons (`ASP:RadioButton` tags) are not being grouped like they should; selecting one of them doesn't deselect the rest.  I've set the `GroupName` property on them already, but I don't see that being rendered in the HTML anywhere via Firebug.  A google search [tells me](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm) that the "name" attribute on `<input type='radio>` is what determines its group membership, but ASP is using that already as some kind of unique identifier.  Each radio button looks something like this when rendered to HTML:

```
<input id="{asp_garbage_naming}_ctl01_rbFoo" type="radio"
   name="ctl03$controlName$otherControlName$ctl01$name"
   value="rbHost" checked="checked" />
```

Is there a way to make this work?  Or am I going to have to provide radio button behavior on my own (javascript, etc)?

Comment: Question? Do you need these radio buttons to be server controls (i.e. do you need the runat=server tag)? If not, you could simply have regular html radio buttons on the column and bind any properties to it using the <%#Eval("Property")%> syntax. Just a thought.

Comment: @Icarus - I need them to be accessible by server-side code because I need to persist the values back into a database somehow.  But I could use hidden fields to indicate which one is selected...

Comment: Are you using a asp:radiobox or a asp:radioboxlist ?

Comment: @Mr. Jefferson, yeah, putting the value a hidden field is sort of a hacky way to do it but solves your other issue... One more suggestion: Did you try overriding the OnRowDataBound and assigning the GroupName manually to every row. For example: Item.Attributes.Add("GroupName","MYVALUE_DAMNIT"); Does that get rendered on the markup or not?

Comment: @Icarus - I tried doing that with the `name` attribute in the `ItemDataBound` event of the repeater when I first found the referenced Google result telling me how radio buttons are grouped, and when it didn't work I saw that ASP was using that attribute.  The hidden field is working well right now, though; if you put your suggestion in the form of an answer I'll mark it for you.

Comment: @David - I'm using `<ASP:RadioButton ... />` controls, which is why I have the problem.  If it was a `RadioButtonList`, the grouping would work automatically.

Comment: @Mr. Jefferson Just posted my answer.

Comment: I Meant radiobutton and radiobuttonlist of course :P brainfart

Comment: @David - Ah, I should have figured that out.  Good point though, I'll update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question? Do you need these radio buttons to be server controls (i.e. do you need the runat=server tag)? If not, you could simply have regular html radio buttons on the column and bind any properties to it using the `<%#Eval("Property")%>` syntax. Just a thought

Comment: I ended up doing `<input type='radio' class='myRadioButtonClass' name='myGroupName' data-rowID='<%#Eval("UniqueID") %>' />`.  Works great with a hidden field populated with that RowID attribute using a jQuery click handler on `$('.myRadioButtonClass')`.

Answer (score 1):

A coworker ran across this issue and implemented a jQuery solution.  Here's an excerpt of it:

That gave me the radio button functionality that I wanted, but it prevented me from getting the selected radio button on postback. So I decided to just implement the radio button functionality manually.

```
var radios = $("input:radio");
radios.click(function() {
     radios.removeAttr('checked');
     $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
     return true;
});
```

Which gave me the correct functionality and I could still get the selected radio button and textbox on postback. Probably not the most elegant solution, but I couldn’t find any other way to do it.

Full post:  [Radio button within a repeater problem](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/radio-button-functionality-within-a-repeater/)

Answer (score 1):

In the server side do as follows:

```
protected void rptRepeaterName_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rdbRadioButtonName = e.Item.FindControl("rdbRadioButtonName") as RadioButton;
    Repeater rptRepeaterName = sender as Repeater;
    rdbRadioButtonName.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("return radioSelected('{0}', '{1}')", rptRepeaterName.ClientID, rdbRadioButtonName.ClientID));
}
```

In the javascript do as follows

```
function radioSelected(rptpricelevel, rdbPriceLevel)
{        
    for (cnt = 0; cnt<100; cnt++)
    {            
        var rdbId = rptpricelevel;
        if(cnt < 10)
        {
            rdbId = + '_ctl0' + cnt + '_rdbRadioButtonName';
        }
        else
        {
            rdbId = + '_ctl' + cnt + '_rdbRadioButtonName';
        }
        var rdb = document.getElementById(rdbId);
        if(rdb != null)
        {
            if(rdbId != rdbPriceLevel)
            {
                rdb.checked = false;
            }
        }
     }         
}
```